# How to calculate the median for a part of a column based on unique names from another column (Rstudio)?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, median

I have a data frame with 4 columns (not counting rownames) and >1200 rows.

| (unique cell ID; rownames) | Sample ID | ME.brown | ME.turquoise | ME.blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1t1_bcHTNA | p1t1 | -0.004 | 0.0023 | 0.00683 |
| p1t1_bcHNVA | p1t1 | 0.0054 | -0.0123 | 0.0045 |
| p1t2_bcEZOJ | p1t2 | -0.0022 | 0.00354 | 0.00374 |
| K3-B003528 | LT_S58 | 0.0464 | 0.00734 | -0.0013 |

I have > 1200 unique cell IDs, which correspond to 68 samples (Sample ID) in total. Now, what I want to do is to calculate the median value for each ME (brown, turquoise and blue) PER SAMPLE. So ideally I want to end up with a table containg 68 rows (for every unique sample) and 3 columns for every ME median. I don't know how to do it apart from manually subsetting each of the 68 unique samples, which would not be very efficient.

I would appreciate all help.

BW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `summarise` functions:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>%  
   summarise_all(.funs = median)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ Species, iris, median)
```